# Can't display multiple object in *ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I have received some data throught an API call and then I converted them to display them on my angular template but it shows me an empty object, here is my objects what's they looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upCo9.png)

and this is my store.ts code what looks like:

```
export class Store implements OnInit {
  store: Store[];
ngOnInit() {
    this.getStore();
  }

  getStore() {
    this.storeService.getAll().subscribe(((response: Store[]) => {
      let data = response['data'];
      for(let  obj in data ) {
        this.store =  data[obj];
        console.log(this.store)
      }
    }));
}
```

and here is my store.html layout:

```
<div*ngFor="let key of store | keyvalue ; let i = index" >
        <ul 
            (click)="onPatch(i)">
            <li>{{key.name}}</li>
            <span>{{key.date}}</span>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**UPDATED:**

if I make like this:

```
this.store= response['data'];
    console.log(this.store);
```

it will give me a dynamic object like the screenshot bellow and that's why I made my operation on that object:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGVHV.png)

Comment: if `response['data']` returns the array in the image of the console it is not `Store[]` like you have it typed in the subscribe callback. Its `{ data: Store[] }`

Answer (score 2):

If `data` already contains your array, can you just do this:

```
  getStore() {
    this.storeService.getAll().subscribe(((response: Store[]) => {
      this.store = response['data'];
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in fact, I need to make an operation on my real response['data'] when I got them with my API, unless it will show as I've updated in my question

Comment: @JosephWu  please, take a look for the updated question

Answer (score 1):

The loop that you have inside the subscription of the http request override each previous object and you end up keeping only the last one when the loop ends. You should remove that loop and then it will work just fine.

Comment: I made  for loops inside my html while assigning the original data to store but did not worked: *ngFor="let key of store " 
            *ngFor="let k of key | keyvalue ; let i = index"

Comment: If you want nested loops you have to wrap it in different div elements.

Answer (score 0):

As @DeborahK states based on the info you've given us `response.data` contains the array

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cant-display-multiple-object-in-ngfor-loop?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

It works here ^ maybe you can fork that and modify to show the issue.

Comment: What exactly isn't working, can you make a stackblitz to demonstrate

Comment: For now it worked fine, I just received received response['data'] and then I applied a *ngFor loop on my html layout, I just removed for loop on the getStore method :)